# Does Hel have a role in Ragnarok?

Tags: norse, ragnarok

During Ragnarok, Fenrir the wolf kills Odin and is then killed by Vidar. The Midgard Serpent Jormungandand and Thor kill each other.

What role does Hel, Loki's other child by Angrboda, play?

Comment: I read somewhere that she conquered helheim so she more than likely gave all of those people that loki had as help but still didn't get involved, I assume she's as cunning as her father.

Comment: I think that hel does die in Ragnarok because Baldur and hod come back from the underworld.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None, as far as we know. She is not mentioned at all in either the poem *Voluspa*, which describes the event of Ragnarok, nor in Snorri's version of events in the *Prose Edda*. All he says is that when Loki arrives at the battle-field of Vigrid, he will have "all Hel's people with him". (Faulkes: 51)

After the Ragnarok, "Balder and Hod will arrive from Hel", where they were both living since their deaths earlier in the mythology. (Faulkes: 56) Snorri also says that there will be places for good and bad people after Ragnarok, the bad one being at Nastrands. Whether Hel will occupy it, or whether she died, is unknown.

(I'm quoting from Anthony Faulkes' translation of the Prose Edda. You can find a [PDF version here](http://vsnrweb-publications.org.uk/EDDArestr.pdf), or you can see another translation at [Sacred Texts](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/pre/pre04.htm).